# C++ Pass struct member as argument

Tags: c++, struct, arguments

I have a function which calculates a struct based on input parameters.
Is it possible to write a function which returns only a certain variable of the calculated struct by passing the desired variable as an argument?
The problem is that the struct has to be created and calculated INSIDE the function, so I only know the future variable names of the struct's members.

Essentially what I want is to replace the following hard-coded "->member1" part by a variable which I have as an argument to the main "DoSomethingSpecific" function.

```
double DoSomethingSpecific()
{
  struct *s = CalculateStruct();
  DoSomethingElse(s->member1);
}
```

EDIT:
I created a minimal example based on an answer which works now and solves the substantial problem of passing struct members as variables to function without creating the struct itsself. However, the data type (int) has to be known before in this case (otherwise templates would help if needed)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct MyStruct
{
   int a;
   int b;
};

int GetVariable(int MyStruct::* field)
{
   MyStruct *_myStruct = new MyStruct();
   _myStruct ->a = 1;
   _myStruct ->b = 2;

   return _myStruct->*field;
}

int main( )
{
   int my_variable = GetVariable(&MyStruct::a); 
   return 0;   
}
```

Comment: You could have a pointer to member. Seems slightly sketchy, though.

Comment: How can I have a pointer to the member if my struct does not exist before the function call?

Comment: The instance of the structure or the structure itself? You don't need an instance to have a pointer to member.

Comment: If `member1` is an integer (`int`) then just create a `DoSomethingElse` function that takes an `int` argument? Then you can pass *any* `int` value or variable (member or not) to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass in a pointer-to-data-member:

```
double DoSomethingSpecific(double Struct::* field)
{
  Struct *s = CalculateStruct();
  DoSomethingElse(s->*field);
}
```

Then to call it:

```
DoSomethingSpecific(&Struct::member1);
```

Edit, a fix based on your edited question:

```
int GetVariable(int MyStruct::* field)
{
    MyStruct *_myStruct = new MyStruct();
    _myStruct->a = 1;
    _myStruct->b = 2;

    return _myStruct->*field;
}
```

Comment: now that sir, is syntax-o-hell :D but I suppose it works

Comment: @Creris: if you think a pointer to data member is nasty, you haven't been using C++ very long.  ;-)

Comment: well Ive seen a lot, but I actually never saw any practical use of ->* or .* so it is kind of surprising. SFNIAE is far worse overall

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I tried it in a minimal example, which I copied now to the question to narrow the problem more down.
But the syntax of Struct::* field does not seem to work as it doesn't compile:
error: expected unqualified-id before ‘*’ token
error: ‘field’ was not declared in this scope
error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token

Comment: @user1810304: I edited my answer with a fix for your new code.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your solution now solved my substantial problem. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you know its type you can pass a pointer to it. When constructing the Struct you initialize the member using the pointer.